# Docker: Nginx PHP-FPM CURL freeze server

Tags: php, docker, nginx, curl

In the NGINX container, the server (site 1), a PHP (php-fpm) script get-curl.php is called on it that makes a CURL request to the URL (site 2), which is located on the same server as a virtual host. Then NGINX hangs. Only restarting it helps. If I move the script from site 1 to another server (site 3) no problem occurs. What could it be?

get-curl.php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site2.com/get.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else echo $result;

curl_close ($ch);
```

get.php:

`echo 'ok';`

Comment: Have you checked nginx and php-fpm logs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there are no errors or warnings

Comment: Missing the nginx.conf you use

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to php_module Apache in PHP-FPM environment and the problem was solved. It turned out that CURL, when executed from PHP-FPM, does not have a timeout (and the forced ones do not work correctly with several requests at the same time), because of this, all processes were clogged and the server hung